# How to handle gender and sexual orientation on a form with select boxes more inclusively?

Tags: forms, language, community, community-management

The existing question and the answers for it are not satisfying when one wants to be more inclusive.

Gender as Male, Female or No Answer works for some sites, but not others.

Taking the view that Gender is not the same as Sex (assigned at birth based on bodily characteristics).

Would it be more inclusive to include these two options: Transgender Male, Transgender Female?

So instead would more inclusive options be the following?

Gender Identity

- Male
- Female
- Transgender Male
- Transgender Female
- No Answer

Sexual Orientation

- Straight
- Lesbian
- Gay
- Bisexual
- Asexual
- No Answer

Gender Expression could also be included, but I think most people would find that too confusing (defined on GLAAD's website linked below)

I'm going off what I've read on [GLAAD's Transgender Glossary of Terms](http://www.glaad.org/reference/transgender).

Thanks!

Comment: "Gender is not the same as Sex" - but "Gender" **is** the same as "Sex"?

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on the content of the site, if it was an adult site you might want to include the transgender options.

But don't transgender people identify themselves as either male or female?  Why not leave it at that...or if that isn't enough, put "other" which often puts a smile on someone's face.

Comment: Some people might take offense with this statement "if it was an adult site you might want to include the transgender options".

Comment: Second rule of busines, "you can please some of the people some of the time, but you can't please all of the people all of the time." Go with what you think is appropriate. There is no "right" answer here.

Comment: @Drew, if people choose to be offended, that's none of my business.